pass through a date or string getElementsByName
I have a little code which puts a date into a text field called Receiptdate.
function changeValue(o){
    document.getElementsByName('ReceiptDate')[0].value=(o);                 
}

I have an image which when I click on it, it sends
onclick="changeValue(<%=MyDate%>)"

I change the value using Visual Basic to change MyDate.
The number I pass through is a date i.e. 2052024
How can I make it show 2/05/2024 or 02/05/2024

show a snippet of what you have

Your input value should have a correct format. It is difficult to determine the day and month number in your input. it looks like 20/05/2024 although you wrote 02/05/2024.
If you can get the the format DDMMYYYY then you can change it to dd/mm/yyyy
lest take this input 1112024 What date is this? October fist of  January 11? But if i write it 01112024 now you can get it.

The number I am passing through was 2nd May 2024. In the UK we write it as 02/05/2024 but as a single number it passes it through as 2052024 it doesn't put the 0 in front. I have tried making my input as a string "02052024" and also as the string 02/05/2024. It doesnt show anything if I put a string in.

Does this answer your question? How do I format a date in JavaScript?

Include the code where MyDate is defined and how it's being passed to the function.

Basically I use Visual Basic to produce a number. I can have this as a integer a string or a date. The code I have only seems to pass through a value. I need to be able to pass through a string and put it in the field. That would sort everything out. It's probably simple for other people but I seem to have tried everything. .

To produce the number I am trying to pass through, I have 3 variables, day, month and year. At the moment I have tried converting all numbers to a string and adding them all together (with and without "/" seperators) . I have tried multiplying the day x 1000000, the month x 10000 and adding them together with the year. This gives a number by converting 02/02/2024 to 2022024. This passes through ok but I need the text field to show the date as 02/02/2024. I can combine d m y in any combination of string, number or date but only the number seems to work with the code I have.

Sorry for being a bit stupid

Hi All, thanks for trying to help but I have fixed it. All it needed was single speech marks inserting instead of onclick="changeValue(<%=MyDate%>)" I just use onclick="changeValue('<%=MyDate%>')"
